# Custom Post Type without an archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, redirect

I have a custom post type called book where I set `'has_archive' => false`. When I access mywebsite.com/book, it's loading mywebsite.com/book/book-1, but I'm expecting load the 404 page. Is this a WordPress feature? How can I disable/change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a WordPress feature?

Yes, and the redirect is being done by [`redirect_canonical()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/), but the URL is determined by [`redirect_guess_404_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_guess_404_permalink/):

> `redirect_guess_404_permalink()`
>
> Attempts to guess the correct URL for a 404 request based on query
> vars.

So what's happening in your case is, WordPress attempts to find a post having `book` in the slug (`post_name`), and then if found, WordPress loads that post instead of showing a 404 error page.

> How can I disable/change this?

1. Completely disable `redirect_canonical()` (which WordPress core hooks on [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect)) if the current URL *path* is exactly `book` as in `example.com/book/` and `example.com/book?foo=bar`.

   So for example, you can use the [`parse_request` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) to disable the canonical redirect:

   ```php
   add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse_392546' );
   function wpse_392546( $wp ) {
       if ( 'book' === $wp->request ) {
           remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or you can use [`do_redirect_guess_404_permalink`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_redirect_guess_404_permalink/) to disable just the attempt of guessing the correct URL as mentioned above.

   So you could use the same hook and function as used in option 1 above, but replace the `remove_action()` line with:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'do_redirect_guess_404_permalink', '__return_false' );
   ```